# Does anyone have a good example of how to use Synapse's Heartbeat function?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus, ararat-synapse

I am using Synapse for Delphi, but when during HTTP downloads, of course, the GUI freezes.  Looking at the documentation, they suggest using the OnHeartbeat method.

(See http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public:howto:heartbeat )

Unfortunately, they don't actually give any code example, and while the concept is simple, the usage is non-obvious.

Is this a per socket (object) setting, or a per application (class) setting?  Also, The callback procedure itself is defined as an object, which is a bit unusual.   Is anyone who has actually used this willing to share a sample code snippit?

Answer (score 2):

Although I would suggest running your download in a seperate thread, reading the documentation you'd have to hook a event handler to the OnHeartBeat event.

In that event handler, you could call `Application.ProcessMessages()` but that is just dangerous due to the possibility of events being fired before you'd actually want them. I would use a custom method to invoke the Paint routine only. You could just pass the handle of your form as parameter, or cast any control to a TWinControl and use the handle property. This will just repaint the form/control, but not allow mouse/keyboard interaction.

```
procedure AllowRepaints(h: HWND);
var
  m: tMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(m, h, WM_PAINT, WM_PAINT, PM_REMOVE) do
    DispatchMessage(m);
end;
```

Comment: Heh, I've had issues getting threads to work reliably across Windows/MacOS/Windows sometimes, so I took the simpler way and went even farther, and just use another *process* for the internet calls, but thank you for the sample, I think many people will find it useful.

Comment: "..., reading the documentation you'd have to hook a event handler to the OnHeartBeat event."   This is exactly what I was looking for code to do.  (Note that I am not using the visual components).